# PHP - Namespace not found, autoload project with composer

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

I'm quite new to autoloading and namespaces, and attempting to add namespaces to my MVC project.

So In my composer I added:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "prj\\app\\": "app/",
        "prj\\app\\controller\\": "app/controller/",
        "prj\\app\\classes\\": "app/classes/"
    }
}
```

And then updated composer and ran the autodump command.

I then went back to my app to try use one of these namespaces however I just get the following back:

```
use \app\classes\engine; // use statement I tried

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app\classes\engine' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web\index.php:87 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web\index.php on line 87
```

I'm not sure why it is unable to find the class using the namespace, here's my entire folder structure if it may be of any use:

```
PRJ
├───app
│   ├───classes
│   └───controller
├───web
│   └───index.php
├───vendor
│   ├───bin
│   ├───composer
│   ├───...
└───view
    ├───bootstrap
    └───default
```

/app stores the logic such as controllers and classes.

/web is the web root - the index.php is the page which visitors see and also everything is handled through here.

/vendor is the composer directory where my dependencies are stored.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things going wrong. First of all, you're adding duplicate namespaces in your composer.json:

The lines:

```
"prj\\app\\controller\\": "app/controller/",
"prj\\app\\classes\\": "app/classes/"
```

Are unnecessary as they are already covered by:

```
"prj\\app\\": "app/",
```

As long as the directory under `app` matches the name of the namespace you use, there is no need to define it explicitly. So you can just add:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "prj\\app\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

Secondly, your `use` statement seems off, you're trying:

```
use \app\classes\engine;
```

The leading slash should not be neccessary here, if you are already in the same namespace. Additionally, you're autoloading your namespaces as `prj\app` and not `app`, so you're missing the `prj` bit. It should look something like this (when this is a file inside the `app` folder):

```
<?php

namespace prj\app\controller;

use prj\app\classes\engine;

class MyController
{
    /**
     * @var engine
     */    
    private $engine;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // This should now work since engine should be autoloaded
        $this->engine = new engine();
    }
}
```

Also take a look at the [PSR-0 naming conventions](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) as you don't seem to follow them. Class names and namespace folders should be capitalized, like `App\Classes\Engine` instead of `app\classes\engine`.

Comment: Hi, I have made these changes to my app but now when I visit said route which is associated with this controller, I get an error "Invalid callback specified.",  

This is what I had been using, the first argument of the array is required to be mapped to the controller whereas the 2nd should be pointed to the method of the controller: 

$app->route('GET /test', array('AutoController','index'));

Comment: The routing file is located in app/routing/*.php, these are required into web/index.php using a foreach.